# Finding average of values against key using RDD in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have created RDD with first column is Key and rest of columns are values against that key. Every row has a unique key. I want to find average of values against every key. I created Key value pair and tried following code but it is not producing desired results. My code is here.

```
val rows = 10
val cols = 6
val partitions = 4
lazy val li1 = List.fill(rows,cols)(math.random)
lazy val li2 = (1 to rows).toList
lazy val li =  (li1, li2).zipped.map(_ :: _)
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("First spark").setMaster("local[*]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val rdd = sc.parallelize(li,partitions)

val gr = rdd.map( x => (x(0) , x.drop(1)))
val gr1 = gr.values.reduce((x,y) => x.zip(y).map(x => x._1 +x._2 )).foldLeft(0)(_+_)
gr1.take(3).foreach(println)
```

I want result to be displayed like

```
1 => 1.1 ,
2 => 2.7
```

and so on for all keys

Comment: Not sure what your code is supposed to be doing. `lazy val li = (li1, li2).zipped.map(_ :: _)` doesn't even compile. If you are building a (key, value) RDD where the value is a list of all the other columns, what do you mean by averaging the values, i.e. two lists?

Comment: @norbertk lazy val li = (li1, li2).zipped.map(_ :: _) is creating new list by taking first row of li1 and concatenates it with li2 , as li1 contains keys and li2 contains values and now i combined them in li. That li is further passed to create RDD.

Answer (score 0):

First I am not sure what this line is doing,

```
lazy val li =  (li1, li2).zipped.map(_ :: _)
```

Instead, you could do this,

```
lazy val li =  li2 zip li1
```

This will create the List of tuples of the type (Int, List[Double]).

And the solution to find the average values against keys could be as below,

```
rdd.map{ x => (x._1, x._2.fold(0.0)(_ + _)/x._2.length) }.collect.foreach(x => println(x._1+" => "+x._2))
```

Comment: lazy val li =  (li1, li2).zipped.map(_ :: _) and lazy val li =  li2 zip li1 are producing same output and code is working fine but performance is slow when experiments are done on huge data set, assume data set with 100000 rows and 100 attributes.